# Reducing a power series to a rational function

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have the series $$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n 2n x^{(2n -1)}$$
It turns out that this series is equal to the function $$\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}$$

Is there a general method that would demonstrate this fact beforehand? I'm looking for an algorithm that expresses a power series as a rational function whenever the power series converges to a rational function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no single method for summing all power series. However, there is the sum of a geometric series:
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k=\frac1{1-x}
$$
Substitution yields
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^kx^{2k}=\frac1{1+x^2}
$$
Taking the derivative gives
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty(-1)^k2kx^{2k-1}=\frac{-2x}{(1+x^2)^2}
$$